# Property `role` does not exist on type `User | AdapterUser` in NextAuth

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I am attempting to build a NextJS application that implements NextAuth. I am encountering the following error in my `[...nextauth].ts` when configuring my callbacks:

```js
Type error: Property 'role' does not exist on type 'User | AdapterUser'.
  Property 'role' does not exist on type 'User'.

  56 |     jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
  57 |       // First time JWT callback is run, user object is available
> 58 |       if (user && user.id && user.role) {
     |                                   ^
  59 |         token.id = user.id;
  60 |         token.role = user.role;
  61 |       }
```

The complete callback section of code looks like this:

```js
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
      // First time JWT callback is run, user object is available
      if (user && user.id && user.role) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.role = user.role;
      }
      return token;
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      if (token && token.id && token.role) {
        session.id = token.id;
        session.role = token.role;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
```

I am using the CredentialProvider with an email and a password. Here is `authorize`:

```js
    async authorize(credentials) {
      if (!credentials || !credentials.email) return null;

      const dbCredentials = await executeAccountQuery(
        `SELECT password FROM auth WHERE email=?`,
        [credentials.email]
      );

      if (Array.isArray(dbCredentials) && "password" in dbCredentials[0]) {
        const isValid = await compare(
          credentials.password,
          dbCredentials[0].password
        );

        if (isValid) {
          return {
            id: "5",
            role: 99,
            name: "John Smith",
            email: credentials.email,
          };
        }
        return null;
      }
      return null; // login failed
    },
```

Because of the way the `authorize` function is working, I know for a fact that the `User` object will have a `role` appended to it (because I have tested it), but I cannot figure out a way to handle this error and get rid it.

Similarily, I also get an error with the `session` callback where the `session.id` and `session.role` are also not present on `Session`.

Answer (score 18):

After a lot of digging through the internet and some trial and error, I was able to figure out how to solve this problem.

You will need to manually extend the `Session`, `User` and `JWT` types by doing the following:

1. Create `types/next-auth.d.ts` in your root project directory.
2. Insert the following into the file:

```js
import { Session } from "next-auth";
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    id: string;
    role: number;
  }

  interface User {
    id: string;
    role: number;
  }
}

declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  interface JWT {
    id: string;
    role: number;
  }
}
```

3. Run `npm run build` and verify that it builds correctly.

Comment: This is not working with adapter users

Answer (score 9):

Type Definition:

`types/next-auth.d.ts`:

```
import { DefaultUser } from 'next-auth';
declare module 'next-auth' {
    interface Session {
        user?: DefaultUser & { id: string; role: string };
    }
    interface User extends DefaultUser {
        role: string;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
async session({ session, user }) {
    if (session?.user) {
        session.user.id = user.id;
        session.user.role = user.role;
    }

    return session;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps anyone else, here's the official documentation: https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript#main-module

It also doesn't really matter where you declare your module. I was able to extend my User type with a role in the following way in the same file where I set my auth options (src/server/auth.ts).

```
import {
  type DefaultSession,
  type DefaultUser,
} from "next-auth";   

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session extends DefaultSession {
    user: DefaultSession["user"] & {
      id: string;
    };
  }
  interface User extends DefaultUser {
    role: Role;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those using Auth.js (version 5), I put this inside my auth.ts file and it worked:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface User {
    // Add your additional properties here:
    givenName?: string | null;
    preferLanguage?: string | null;
  }
}

declare module "@auth/core/adapters" {
  interface AdapterUser {
    // Add your additional properties here:
    givenName: string | null;
    preferLanguage: string | null;
  }
}
```

The official documentation doesn't include the Adapter part so I had to figuere it out by myself: https://authjs.dev/getting-started/typescript